# How to run Slax Linux as Hyper-V VM on Windows?

Tags: linux, windows-10, hyper-v, window, slax

Has anybody tried running [Slax](https://www.slax.org) as VM in Hyper-V on Windows and can share his experience? I did a quick try but could not make it work - actually I even could not start the ISO

[image]

Comment: What problem did you encounter?

Comment: I added an screenshot of the error

Comment: Are you trying to boot the ISO as your disk image?  I am betting that the SCSI controller is expecting a VHD (or similar) disk.  Not an ISO.

Comment: Try a Gen1 VM instead.

Comment: I would recommend looking at the specific version of Windows 10 you have, as the build number will tell you the exact capabilities of the Hyper-V VM. Linux can be very limited in Hyper-V, with sound not even working in some cases. Ubuntu is usually your best bet for full functionality. I have had little luck with Hyper-V and Linux myself.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Actually Slax is meant to be used as a live distro and usually would  be booted from USB stick or CD. My hope was that it would boot so I can install it on the virtual disk. Is it possible  to write the content of the ISO to a VHD or other disk format supported by Hyper-V?

Comment: See my answer below.  After it boots.. it's just like any other system with a hard disk.  Install it if you want.

Comment: @Joshua_Nurczyk is not wrong.  I have had no problem using Linux with Hyper-V as a non-desktop solution but it certainly is more lack-luster than running VirtualBox.  I would use VirtualBox or VMWare for the full whiz-bang desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go into the Hyper-V manager.
2. Choose New->Virtual Machine ***(NOT QUICK CREATE)***
3. Fill out each of the screens with whatever you want.. ***EXCEPT***
4. Choose "Generation 1" under "Specify Generation"
5. Select `Install an operation system from a bootable CD/DVD-ROM`
6. Then choose the radio `(*) Image file (.iso)` and point it at your *slax-64bit-x.xx.x.iso* file.

Fire it up!! :)

[image]